# Javascript IDE for agile development

Tags: javascript, ide, agile

Which IDE will suit agile development at its best? When I talk about agile, I primarily think about refactoring flexibility, powerful code browsing and all kinds of code inspection / warnings tips (similar to JSlint etc). Optionally, SVN/GIT integration would be nice to get supported as well as an ability to run both on Unix and Windows. Freeware or commercial - both options are valid.

**Update**: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477170/javascript-review-refactoring-tools) post, but the tools there support mainly Microsoft platforms (which is good thing, but alternatives are welcomed as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally chosen IntelliJ Idea Ultimate Edition - works out of the box, has an impressive code browsing and refactoring capabilities. Tried Eclipse and other related vendors, but (personally) found the installation procedure not that as 1-2-3 clicks easy as expected. All that said, this is only my personal subjective impression.

Answer (score 1):

vim or Sublime text 2 combined with unix.

Why? Because JS is dynamic. So just use a text editor.

All IDEs leak with false positives on their code analysis.

Comment: That's what I use now (with a bunch of plugins) - I am sure there are tools that can perform better. Interpreter languages still have structure and syntax no simple text editor is aware of.

Comment: @BreakPhreak if your already using vim stick to it. It's streamlined, it's fast, it's efficient, it does one thing really well. All IDEs do a lot of things mediocrely

Comment: Sublime Text is spectacular for JavaScript development.

Answer (score 0):

[Apatana](http://www.aptana.com/) is pretty good - it's available standalone or as an Eclipse plugin so you shouyld be able to use most of the support that that Eclipse has for SVN etc

Answer (score 0):

even Eclipse EE with corresponding facet is quite good. But I will Also recommen you Apatana+Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I have been using PHPStorm for a good year now: http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/.
It has an integrated GIT and SVN Client and you can run external applications such as jslint. You can include libraries such as jQuery and it has a good code formatter (one that actually works).

Also have a look at Webstorm: http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/.
(Webstorm = PHPStorm - PHP)

Comment: Thanks, but I am mostly considered about refactoring and code browsing options.

Comment: Take a look at http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/features/index.html#Advanced_JavaScript_Editor

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Though I see that changing function name (for example) is not supported.